# DevServer fails after updating to java 6u31

Tags: java, google-app-engine

This is the error I recieve. When I revert to using 6u30, it works fine. AppEngine must be updated now to fix this bug.

```
Initializing App Engine server
   [ERROR] Unable to start App Engine server
Unable to start embedded HTTP serverjava.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to restore the previous TimeZone
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.restoreLocalTimeZone(DevAppServerImpl.java:228)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:164)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1068)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:811)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: defaultZoneTL
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.restoreLocalTimeZone(DevAppServerImpl.java:222)
... 6 more
[ERROR] shell failed in doStartupServer method

com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:102)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1068)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:811)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a known bug: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6928

Workaround is to add this line to your run config:

```
-Dappengine.user.timezone=UTC
```

For some people it must be:

```
-Dappengine.user.timezone.impl=UTC
```

Seems that the latter works if GWT is included; if you don't use GWT along with GAE, then use the former.

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class \Dappengine.user.timezone=UTC
i got this error

Answer (score 5):

As it was said before - download App Engine for Java 1.6.3.1 from this url: http://code.google.com/appengine/downloads.html
Then unzip it to some folder and then go to Eclipse, choose **Window -> Preferences -> Google -> App Engine -> Add** and find folder with downloaded files. After it make sure that you check the new version as active and click OK. This solution worked for me.

Comment: Or you can just get the sdk using the eclipse update url: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7 (eclipse > help > install new software)

Answer (score 1):

This bug seems to be fixed with GAE 1.6.4

java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04-415-11M3635)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01-415, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

The workaround did not work for me.

I have solved the problem by uninstalling jdk and runtime env 1.7.0_03 and installing jdk and runtime env 1.7.0_02 (JDK 7, update 2 from archive - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html#jdk-7u2-oth-JPR

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution that worked for me is to download appengine-java-sdk-1.6.3.1 and to configure this as standard appengine sdk.