# Error on running a simple App Engine project

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm new to Google App Engine, and I tried to create a test project on Ubuntu 11.04 following this quick tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3GT4-m_6RQ&feature=relmfu 
and I have this error when i click on "debug > web application"

---

### There is a new version of the SDK available.

Latest SDK:
Release: 1.6.2
Timestamp: Tue Jan 03 19:15:38 CET 2012
API versions: [1.0]

---

Your SDK:
Release: 1.6.1
Timestamp: Mon Dec 12 23:53:13 CET 2011
API versions: [1.0]

---

Please visit http://code.google.com/appengine for the latest SDK.

---

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to restore the previous TimeZone
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.restoreLocalTimeZone(DevAppServerImpl.java:228)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:164)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:164)
at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>    (DevAppServerMain.java:113)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:89)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: defaultZoneTL
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1899)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.restoreLocalTimeZone(DevAppServerImpl.java:222)
... 5 more
```

Can anybody determine where the problem is? I also had problems trying to create a GWT app and a Python App Engine project.

Comment: Thanks but i got this error now : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to restore the previous TimeZone
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.restoreLocalTimeZone(DevAppServerImpl.java:228)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:164)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:164)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:113)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possible duplicate of: [DevServer fails after updating to java 6u31](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414106/devserver-fails-after-updating-to-java-6u31)

However, this problem seems to be documented (with solution) here:
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6928

From the site:

> Workaround - start the GAE with the following JVM parameter:
> -Dappengine.user.timezone=UTC
>
> (with eclipse, go to "run configuration", under the "Arguments" tab add "-Dappengine.user.timezone=UTC" to the VM arguments line. With maven-gae-plugin, add -Dappengine.user.timezone=UTC to the plugin configuration).
> Good luck, and hopefully Google will support JDK u31 soon enough.

Comment: It depends on your configuration, but you might have to use `-Dappengine.user.timezone.impl=UTC` instead.