# Error while starting a GAE/GWT project: Unable to restore the previous TimeZone

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, gae-eclipse-plugin

When I try to run a GWT App Engine project using the Eclipse plugin, I get the following error:

```
Initializing App Engine server
[ERROR] Unable to start App Engine server
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to restore the previous TimeZone
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.restoreLocalTimeZone(DevAppServerImpl.java:228)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:164)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1068)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:811)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: defaultZoneTL
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1899)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.restoreLocalTimeZone(DevAppServerImpl.java:222)
    ... 6 more
[ERROR] shell failed in doStartupServer method
Unable to start embedded HTTP server
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at      com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:102)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1068)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:811)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
```

Comment: does this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/q/9414106/617373 ?

Answer (score 8):

Chris Cashwell provided the [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9759553/1093087). But for people like myself who are relatively new to Eclipse, here are more explicit instructions (which I came across [here](http://tech.chitgoks.com/2012/03/12/fix-the-unable-to-restore-the-previous-timezone-in-gwt/)):

1. Right-click project directory in Project Explorer window
2. Select **Run As** > **Run Configurations...**
3. Go to **Arguments** tab
4. In **VM Arguments** textbox, add one of the following parameters mentioned by Chris:

   - `-Dappengine.user.timezone.impl=UTC` (this worked in my case)
   - `-Dappengine.user.timezone=UTC`
5. Click **Apply** then **Run**

In my case, this was done specifically in the context of a PlayN project I am working on, so I was right-clicking the HTML folder. In the end, my VM arguments looked something like this:

```
-Xmx512m -javaagent:/long/path/to/appengine-agent.jar -Dappengine.user.timezone.impl=UTC
```

Answer (score 3):

See [this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6928). For me, it was fixed by downgrading the JDK from 1.7.0_03 -> 1.7.0_02. Other things that have been purported to work are adding `-Dappengine.user.timezone=UTC` (or in some cases `-Dappengine.user.timezone.impl=UTC`) to the JVM flags.

Comment: I fixed it but the problem is, i have to do the same trick every time i need to create a new project

Answer (score 1):

i got this error, and found `port already in use` in the console.

I closed eclipse and killed javaw.exe. Then everything worked fine.